# Many requests over port 445 on Ubuntu VPS, what could it mean?

Tags: port, hacking, tcpdump, spoofing

I own a small VPS hosted by Hetzner on which i run a small Minecraft game server. The VPS is running on Ubuntu, and the only software i installed are Java JRE and the required software to run a Minecraft game server (+ additional plugins).

I ran a tcpdump over night and here is the result:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=15hYd2QzREAW_d8KodLyVhUVleu1OxCYz

Could anyone help me read it?

Is it regular?

First of july i received a mail from abuse@hetzner.com (my host) stating that Columbia University sent them an automated notice regarding unwanted traffic coming from my ip address.

Here is the original Columbia University message: https://pastebin.com/3kMy98kw

But it also said:

> It is possible that this alert is the result of a reflection attack against your network with a spoofed origin matching Columbia
>   University's network.   Details are provided below.  Please take all
>   necessary steps to mitigate such attacks, or ignore this notice if
>   this traffic is spoofed.

So could that be just a random occourrence? Or is my server hacked?

Comment: If you are running no software that normally does this kind of activity, then yes, your server has been compromised. Also note: Hobby (minecraft) servers are [off-topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: @Sven could not find more appropriate forums.. However, could you help me read that dump? Is the traffic going or coming on port 445? Is there a way to find out which process is causing it?

Comment: Destroy this host, rebuild it with an clean updated firewalled operating system, and restore backups. If you need to know the specifics of what happened in your environment, hire a security consultant.